# Json Object assign to interface is not working angular2

Tags: json, typescript, angular

I'm trying to use http get with observable, I create a service for that and return a object.

**my inteface**

```
export interface Login {
login : boolean;
username : string;
type: string;
token: string;
email: string;
name: string;
}
```

**my service**

```
getUsers(){
this.url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/users';
return this.callApi(this.url);
}

callApi(url: string): Observable<Login[]> {
return this.http.get(url).map(this.extractData).catch(this.handleError);
}

private extractData(res: Response) {
let body = res.json();
// console.log(body['result']);
return body.result || { };
}
```

whan i use this service in my component it return object like below.

```
[Object, Object]
  0: Object
    email: "admin@gmail.com"
    id: "5788995b008b2f1af2e33f78"
    name: "admin"
    type: "admin"
    user_name: "admin"
  __proto__: Object
 1: Object
 length: 2
```

when I try to map this onto array of Login object it not working. when I try to get console log on it its shows [] this.

**my component**

```
private login : Login[] = [];
mode = 'Observable';

constructor(private userService: UserService) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.getUsers();
}

getUsers(){
  this.userService.getUsers().subscribe(
   data => this.login = data
  );

 console.log(this.login);
 }
```

what wrong with my code?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated: 
`console.log(this.login);` prints an empty array because the promise has not finished, so if you want to print the data array, move that statement inside the subscribe function.

The code should be like this

```
getUsers(){
  this.userService.getUsers().subscribe(
   data => {
             this.login = data;
             console.log(this.login);
  }
  );
```

}

Comment: I did but result is same

Comment: When you print console.log(this.login); the promise has not finished, so the array is empty. Can you move the console log inside the subscribe? function after this.login = data, so it looks like this data => { this.login = data; console.log(this.login); }